# Change authorized roles in derived controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I'm struggling a bit with authorization. I want to have a `BaseController` that defines CRUD operations which only the *Admin* have access to. Then have a `DerivedController` which then allow a *SuperUser* access.

Like so:

```
public class BaseController : ApiController
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public void Foo() {...}
}

public class DerivedController : BaseController
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "SuperUser")]
    public void Foo() { base.Foo(); }
}
```

*The above is a simplified version, so the example appears a bit weird :). Having a single controller with `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, SuperUser")]` isn't an option.*

However this does not work. I'm getting access denied when trying to access `Derived.Foo` as a *SuperUser*.

Is this approach not possible?

Answer (score 0):

The way that `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, SuperUser")]` works is that it is requiring EITHER "Admin" or "SuperUser".

However, since you now have two Authorize attributes, you are now requiring BOTH "Admin" and "SuperUser".

Granting your SuperUser the Admin permission should make your solution approach.